# Facial detection in comics using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier

I have an OpenCV Python script that detects and crops images containing faces using OpenCV for facial detection. Currently, the script uses `'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'`to detect faces but as it is trained on photographs of human faces, it does not suffice for my data set of comics.

Using Python and OpenCV, how can I perform facial detection on comic or cartoon characters?

Has anyone interested in face detection tried using non-photographs?